# embedding ondblclick in generated TR

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

i'm converting an html table from plain old MVC3 to ajax, and wish to keep some of the functionality from the MVC version. specifically the users currently double-click anywhere on a row to get a detailed view of the record associated with the row. this was accomplished with an ondblclick='' in the  tag.

```
@<tr class="@CSSclass" ondblclick="window.location='/Request/Details/@item.ID'">
```

that's the old MVC

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/request/DRequest",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                var accepted
                var cssclass
                var datestr
                var highlite
                var trstr
                if (response[i].NeededByDate - Date.now() / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) < 2) {
                    datestr = '<span class="attention">' + response[i].NeedByDate + '</span>'
                    alert(datestr)
                }
                else {
                    datestr = response[i].NeedByDate

                }
                if (response[i].AcceptedBy != null) {
                    accepted = response[i].AcceptedBy
                    highlite = '<td>'
                }
                else {
                    accepted = '<a href="Request/AcceptRequest/' + response[i].ID + '">Accept</a>'
                    highlite = '<td style="background-color: #eecc88;">'
                }
                if (response[i].Priority == true) {
                    trstr = '<tr class="attention" ondblclick="window.location="/Request/Details/' + response[i].ID + '">'
                }
                else {
                    trstr = '<tr ondblclick="window.location=\'/Request/Details/' + response[i].ID + '\'>'
                }

                var $tr = $(trstr).append(
                $('<td>').html(datestr),
                $('<td>').text(response[i].RequestedBy),
                $('<td>').text(response[i].UserName),
                $('<td>').text(response[i].RequestedPC),
                $('<td>').text(response[i].RequestType),
                $('<td>').text(response[i].Division),
                $(highlite).html(accepted),
                $('<td>').html(unescape(response[i].ReqTypeIcon))
                ).appendTo('#requestTable');


            }

        }

    });
```

and that's the javascript handling the row creation now. this crashes. returns no rows. if i remove the `ondblclick` from the `trstr` variable it runs. any way around this? maybe i'm escaping incorrectly. thanks!

Comment: the rendered html returns `<tr class="attention" ondblclick="window.location=" request="" details="" 1064"="">` (or whatever ID the row in question has.) i've gotta be unescaping improperly .

Comment: `var loc = "'/Request/Details/" + response[i].ID + "'"` and then `trstr = 'class="attention"'`
`trstr = trstr + ' ondblclick="window.location=' + unescape(loc) + '"'`
and then `var $tr = $('<tr ' + trstr + '>').append(` works!